# mvn invalid target release: 1.7

Tags: java, maven

mvn test :

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) on project vslimit: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.7.0_65

pom:
      `<java-version>`1.7`</java-version>`

> ```
>        `<plugin>`
>             `<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>`
>             `<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>`
>             `<version>3.2</version>`
>             `<configuration>`
>                 `<source>${java.version}</source>`
>                 `<target>${java.version}</target>`
>                 `<encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>`
>             `</configuration>`
>         `</plugin>`
> ```

java -version

> ```
>          java version "1.7.0_65"
>          Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_65-b17)
>          Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
> ```

mvn -v

> ```
>          Apache Maven 3.2.1  Maven home:
>          /Users/vslimit/tool/apache-maven-3.2.1 Java version: 1.7.0_65, vendor:
>          Oracle Corporation Java home:
>          /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
>          Default locale:  platform encoding: UTF-8 OS name: "mac os x",
>          version: "10.10.2", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
> ```

i has try a lot of suggests,ex:java_home or other,but failed

Comment: `java-version` vs `java.version`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your `pom.xml` to have

```
<project>
...
  <properties>
      <java.version>1.7</java.version>
  </properties>
...
</project>
```

Comment: pom has the properties

Comment: make it look like this (structure and the property name )